# Programmatically created ARSCNView doesn't work

Tags: ios, arkit, arscnview

I have created ARSCNView programmatically as the below code. The app runs on my real iPhone (without crashing) but shows a blank/black screen. It doesn't ask for accessing the camera either (I have the line "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" in Info.plist already). With the commented line `sceneView.backgroundColor = .green` I am sure the ARSCNView is created, added, and full screen.

```
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let sceneView = ARSCNView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
        // make sure the sceneView is added and full screen
        //sceneView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add SCNScene to your ARSCNView

```
let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
```

And start ARWorldTrackingConfiguration in viewWillAppear

```
//Inside view will appear
let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
self.sceneView.session.run(config)
```